# Saving session value in database using php

Tags: php, mysql, session, post

I have this

```
session_start();
if ($_SESSION['email']&&$_SESSION['companyID'])
echo $_SESSION['email']."";
else
die("You must be logged in!");
```

and now im saving some data in database, and i want to save the companyID aswell by using createUser.php which contain these but its not saving the companyID

```
$userID=0;
$userRole=$_POST ["role"];
$userEmail = $_POST["userEmail"];
$userPassword = $_POST["userPassword"];
$companyID = $_POST[$_SESSION["companyID"]];
```

// insertion to user_details table

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (userID, email, password,companyID,roleID) VALUES 
                        ('$userID', '$userEmail', '$userPassword','$companyID','$userRole')";
```

Comment: `$companyID = $_SESSION["companyID"];` change this

Comment: `$companyID = $_POST[$_SESSION["companyID"]];` chnage this to either `$companyID = $_SESSION["companyID"];` or `$companyID = $_POST["companyID"];`

Comment: what you trying to get in the $companyID??

Comment: `$company_id` is from session, so cannot come in `POST` request @Ms.Nehal

Comment: @PathikVejani, I thought he might be getting it form post as well, so I suggested both the options. As whichever option the user would be using he would use that one

Comment: @Ms.Nehal OP clearly post this: `session_start();
if ($_SESSION['email']&&$_SESSION['companyID'])
echo $_SESSION['email']."";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing this:

```
$companyID = $_POST[$_SESSION["companyID"]];
```

For this:

```
$companyID = $_SESSION["companyID"];
```